Sense of the word Sturmfrei
I would like to understand the sense of the word "sturmfrei" as in sturmfreie Bude. Does it mean literally free-of-storm, or is the sense more freedom-to-storm.

Literally sturmfrei means free of storm(s). The word was used historically meaning cannot be stormed (by troups), as the Verb "stürmen" (which is a derivative of the noun "Sturm") means also to assault.
In later times it was used in the fixed phrase "sturmfreie Bude", which ("Bude" is "shack", a slightly derogative word for "apartment") first was a students home without the danger of creditors (also: other sources of "assault" or molestation) coming. Later this meaning was transcended to places not endangered by parents coming home (who could, in case of a party taking place there, also become quite a source of molestation).

Superficial answer: sturmfreie Bude is multi-word expression with fixed meaning, see DWDS.
But looking at sturmfrei on its own, it seems to have a military background like can't be stormed/conquered - with the image of same awful parents storming into the room, that seems a reasonable explanation too.

Siehe Grimms Wörterbuch

Hm.. can't this also mean "frei zum Stürmen" which means "allowance to step in at any time" for the visitors of the apartment because there is no control/supervision of the entrance?

FWIW where I come from "sturmfrei haben" was more common than the combination "eine sturmfreie Bude haben" (and with the same meaning).

The military background is at the end of a siege of a town or fortress, where the "Sturm frei!" is the call of the leader of the attacking troops to start the attack. It also exists in "Feuer frei!", the order of the officer to start shooting at the enemy/targets.
